# Androidx.core 1.6.0 throwing the error : Cannot access 'kotlin.Lazy'

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Changing this

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'`

into

`implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'`

is throwing the error ---> [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIXQV.png)

Otherwise No error --->  [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/811Bk.png)

**Gradle(app)**

```
plugins {
 id 'com.android.application'
 id 'kotlin-android'
 id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}

android {
 compileSdkVersion 30
 buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

 defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.saif.jetpacknavigationexample"
     minSdkVersion 21
     targetSdkVersion 30
     versionCode 1
     versionName "1.0"

     testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
 }

 buildTypes {
     release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
 }
 compileOptions {
     sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
     targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
 }
 kotlinOptions {
     jvmTarget = '1.8'
 }
}

dependencies {

 implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
 implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
 implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
 implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
 implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
 testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
 androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

 def nav_version = "2.3.1"

 // Kotlin
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$nav_version"
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$nav_version"
}
```

**Gradle(Project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"
    ext.nav_version = "2.3.1"
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pls make change to 1.5.31, it solves problem for me.

Comment: But he want to use 1.6.0

Comment: Question creator need version he post.